# Filter by COUNT(*)?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to group results and then filter by how many rows are in the group?

Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE COUNT(*) > 1 GROUP BY name
```

Answer (score 108, accepted):

You want to use HAVING to filter on the aggregate function.

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*)
    FROM mytable
    GROUP BY name
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: SUPERSTAR! Just about to test it!

Comment: And the HAVING clause has to go before ORDER BY as well.

Comment: You can also rename the COUNT(*) for readability. `SELECT name, count(*) cnt FROM mytable GROUP BY name HAVING cnt > 1`

Answer (score 15):

You need to use `HAVING`

```
SELECT * FROM mytable GROUP BY name HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Although, `SELECT *` doesn't make much sense when you're grouping. I assume it's just for an example

Answer (score 3):

Use having in your query:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable GROUP BY name having COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 3):

You want a HAVING clause.

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```