# Pesky IF/THEN statement in mysql query

Tags: mysql, database

```
> select * from site, count(*) as count  
> from myTable 
> where year(created_at) = 2012
> group by site order by count DESC limit 10000
```

I'm selecting a massive amount of data that essentially has a really long and useless tail.

I'm trying to cut off this query so it doesn't show anything with less than 500 results.

All of the Googling I've done for the solution to this hasn't proved very helpful.

Any idea how to construct the query to limit this data to only show sites with a count of 500 or more?

Comment: You can filter grouped values with `having`: `select count(*) from tab where y group by z having count(*) > 500`

Comment: @arnep I've got `query = ("select site, count(*) as count from myTable where year(created_at) = 2012
      group by site having count(*) > 500 order by count DESC").to_a` and it's not filtering out anything below 500 for some reason

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from site, count(*) as count  
from myTable 
where year(created_at) = 2012
group by site having count>500 order by count DESC limit 10000
```

You want "having count>500" in there if you only want to select rows with more than 500 results.

WHERE doesn't work on aggregate functions.

Comment: Sean, thanks for your response. I've got this copied exactly and it isn't working for some reason...I'm not sure why.

Comment: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'count(*) as count
from myTable
where year(created_at) = 2012
group by site
havin' at line 1` when I do the query in Sequel Pro

Comment: Is it perhaps because of the "from" line in both lines 1 and 2?

Comment: That would exactly be it. I copied and pasted your query assuming it was functional and simply added "having count>500" where it should go, but now that I look at your query, it doesn't make sense. Should it be this? `select *,count(*) as count from myTable,site...` instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  site , 
  count(*) as val 
from 
  myTable 
where 
  year(created_at) = 2012 
and 
  val > 500 
group by 
  site
HAVING COUNT(*) > 500
```

*edit*

Points go to Sean - I realized I was using MSSQL syntax, not MySQL

Also - refer to [FIlter by COUNT(*) ? - MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664103/filter-by-count-mysql)

Comment: That's not working for some reason. I still get all of those long tail results