# Need to Search MYSQL Query to return items only where num of rows is reached

Tags: mysql

Difficulty explaining what I need:

In a nut shell, this is what I have:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(CITY) FROM `listingsdb` WHERE `style` = 'Traditional' ORDER BY `style` ASC
```

This returns `ALL DISTINCT CITY VALUES` with a `STYLE = Traditional`.

It gave me 840 results, including 800 of these cities have less than 10 results... I need to Reduce / Restrict it further by having it ONLY return values where there are MORE Than 100 Identical City Matches to display that city, and possibly set PRICE value to a minimum of 100,000.

What is the MOST EFFICIENT way to do this?

I do NOT have a specific MySQL table that has `CITYNAME` & `RESULTS` `COLUMN`.

I am trying to stay away from a Nested Loop of constant MySQL queries if it's possible.

Comment: Distinct is not a function

Comment: Ordering by `style` is useless since all records are 'Traditional'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FIlter by COUNT(\*) ? - MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664103/filter-by-count-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

Just group by city.

```
SELECT COUNT(city) as count, city as city 
FROM listingsdb 
WHERE style='Traditional' 
ORDER BY style ASC 
GROUP BY city 
HAVING count > 100
```

Comment: Last `WHERE` should be `HAVING` instead.

Comment: Here the same: ORDER BY must be the last clause. And as Sal pointed out - there's no sence to ORDER BY `style`.

Comment: Thank you guys VERY much! I will try that on Wednesday is my next day back to work, taking a few days off for my birthday.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be perfect for your requirement

```
 SELECT COUNT(CITY) as count, CITY  
    FROM `listingsdb` 
    WHERE 
    `style` = 'Traditional' 
    GROUP BY CITY 
    HAVING count >= 100
```

Comment: `ORDER BY` is misplaced.

Comment: The correct order of clauses is SELECT - FROM - WHERE - GROUP BY - HAVING - ORDER BY

Comment: Thank you guys VERY much! I will try that on Wednesday is my next day back to work, taking a few days off for my birthday.